# Change Magento product price using a cron job

Tags: magento

The price of my product changes over time, so I want to set up a cron job to do so.

Can I just create a quick php script that updates the database?

If so: where are these prices?

If not: what's the best way to do this?

Comment: what have you tired to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

There are good tutorials about this around. This one might be useful as start: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job.

Answer (score 1):

Your easiest option is probably to set up a import dataflow and call that on a cron job.

Spend a few days on one of these two monster threads to get the general idea:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/8542

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/35865

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update product prices in Magento in easier & faster way by using csv file with just two fields: sku & new price then you can follow this great article:
http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/updating-product-prices-in-magento-in-easier-faster-way/

This saves you a lot of your time and hence $$$

Happy E-Commerce!!